# PHP global not available in function

Tags: php

I set up my global like this:

```
require('../scripts/mysql_db.php');
$DB = new mysql_db();
$connectid = $DB->sql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user , $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
```

I then use `$DB` throughout like this:

```
$query1 = $DB->query('SELECT ....');
```

However I wrote a function to use `$DB` and its not accessible for some reason:

```
function deletePendingRow($aOkReason, $aFailReason) {
    $query99 = $DB->query('DELETE .....');
}
```

I think this is a basic php thing, can someone help me understand why.

The `mysql_db` is here: https://github.com/Noitidart/MailtoWebmails-Backend/blob/master/scripts/mysql_db.php

Thanks

edit:
i tried this:

```
function deletePendingRow($aOkReason, $aFailReason) use ($DB, $rowPending) {
```

It doesnt seem to work it tells me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting '{'`

edit 2:

i also tried this:

```
$deletePendingRow = function($aOkReason, $aFailReason) use ($DB, $rowPending) {

};
```

but this throws `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/a1304271/public_html/ajax/approve_pending.php`

Comment: 1) Check if your connection was successful or not 2) Add error reporting to the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` and tell us if you get any. 3) Also do you pass the connection to the function ?

Comment: Where is `$aDB` supposed to come from here?!

Comment: You can't really *set up globals*. You can set variables outside of any function, and even call this a global, but this does not make the variable implicitly available inside functions/methods. Either you need to pass your variable around or use `global $...` inside the function (note that the second option is something you should avoid).

Comment: Oops @deceze tha twas a typo, that was my work around because I couldnt access it haha.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476)

Comment: Thanks @deceze can you please see my edit, I tried the `use` thing its telling me though `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE, expecting '{' `

Comment: `use` is only for ***anonymous functions***.

Comment: Ah thanks @deceze so is there any way to do it without usign `global`? :(

Comment: As the duplicate says: *pass it as parameter*. If that gets too tedious, you'll want to start learning about classes and dependency injection.

Comment: Ah ok thanks much man.

Comment: @deceze i learned a ton from your comments thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define it like to access global variables in the functions

```
global $DB;
```

Although if you are getting the database variable via parameters, then there should be no problem accessing it.

Comment: Thank you! :) I think this will fix it! :)